# Recursive makefile No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile, automake

The project is about a root directory that contains a src directory. I created two makefiles, one at the top directory and the other at the src directory. Here is the makefile of the src directory:

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

## Created by Netbeans

AM_CPPFLAGS = \
   -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""$(localedir)"\" \
   -DPACKAGE_SRC_DIR=\""$(srcdir)"\" \
   -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""$(pkgdatadir)"\"


bin_PROGRAMS = scratchautotool

program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/bin/PR__bin

program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/lib/PR__lib

CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))

scratchautotool_SOURCES = \
     main.c \
     Task.c \
     SeedVP.c

depend :
    makedepend --$(CFLAGS) --$(scratchautotool_SOURCES)
```

The makefile of the root directory is shown below:

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in
## Created by Netbeans

   SUBDIRS = src

   scratchautotooldocdir = ${prefix}/doc/scratchautotool
   scratchautotooldoc_DATA = \
          README\
          COPYING\
          AUTHORS\
          ChangeLog\
          INSTALL\
          NEWS

    INTLTOOL_FILES = intltool-extract.in \
      intltool-merge.in \
      intltool-update.in

    EXTRA_DIST = $(scratchautotooldoc_DATA) \
          $(INTLTOOL_FILES)

    DISTCLEANFILES = intltool-extract \
          intltool-merge \
          intltool-update \
         po/.intltool-merge-cache

   # Remove doc directory on uninstall
   uninstall-local:
   -rm -r $(scratchautotooldocdir)
```

but while I was invoking `make` from the terminal it gave me the following error:

```
   Making all in src
   make[2]: Entering directory `../src'
   make[2]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
   make[2]: Leaving directory `../src'
```

Comment: `--$(scratchautotool_SOURCES)` is going to expand to `--main.c Task.c SeedVP.c` which is quite likely not what you intended or wanted. Similarly `--$(CFLAGS)` will expand to `---I/usr/bin/PR__bin` (or possibly `-- -I/usr/bin/PR__bin` I'd have to test it to be sure) but in either case also not likely what you intended.

Comment: @Etan My source directory contains the 3 file and two header file,  i used makedepend to automatically generate the dependency rule and avoid any mistakes i could do so do you mean this is wrong and regarding cflags, i have folder that contains many header files that the main.c, seedvp.c and so on use in the code

Comment: I mean the use of those variables on the makedepend line is almost certainly not correct as you have too many dashes (unless makedepend has some strange argument requirements). Just look at the command that make indicates it is running when you run `make depend` to see what I mean. Also those `foreach` loops can be replaced with `CFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS))` and `AM_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -L,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS))` for simplicity.

Comment: I run make depend it gives me this error  No rule to make target `depend'.  Stop.

Comment: The `depend` target is only valid in the `src` directory most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution for my question with any one who will encounter the same issue, I have modified the makefile as shown below:

```
all: scratchautotool
depend :
       makedepend $(CFLAGS) $(scratchautotool_SOURCES)
```

but this also gave the same error, so I've searched and I've found that the makedepend didn't exist so I had to install xutils-dev package(which includes the program makedepend) using the below command:

```
  sudo apt-get install xutils-dev
```

but this command solves the above mentioned issue only! but the makefile now has a new issue :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear: it is expecting to find the target `all`, and isn't.  I'm assuming you called `make` without specifying a target; the default is (surprise!) `all`.

Comment: Sorry if my questions seems to be a trivial but as i said before i am a beginner; so do you mean that i should add all: to my makefile but to which file or what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: @Sara - yes just add a all: target to your Makefile.  You can just simply add already existing targets to the all statement.  Example: 'all: depend' and it will just make your depend target.

Comment: The default target in a makefile is the first listed target. `all` is used by convention as that target but any target will do. Which means that the issue here is that something ran `make all` and no such target was listed. Running `make` would have built whatever the first target was.